# Как подключить системные ресурсы файла прошивки Android к запихнутому в Eclipse приложению?

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse

В Eclipse создаю новый проект путем импорта уже разобранного с помощью apktolls приложения и получаю кучу ошибок такого плана:

> error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'color' with value '[[@android](/users/664/androiddev)](/users/664/androiddev):color/bright_foreground_dark').

Содержимое одного из файлов с похожей ошибкой:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark" />
</selector>
```

Ресурс, ссылка на который определяется как ошибка, находится в системном файле прошивки framework-res.apk/res/values/color.xml.

И вот тут возникает вопрос:

**Как подключить данный ресурс в Eclipse?**

Answer (score 1):

Вытащите ресурсы и бросьте их в подкаталог res/ - если что можно указать Eclipse где лежат ресурсы

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! А с вами связаться можно как-то, чтобы немножко подробнее прояснить данный вопрос?